# Getting value which posted via input to the same page with ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to post a value which I get from the input to the same page by using node.js and ejs template. The template works for passing page title, however when I try to pass the value which I get from input it doesn't work. It says "subtitles" array is not defined. This is confusing for me a little bit. Could you help me please?

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const parser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(parser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(parser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.userValue = null;
    next();
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index', {
        topicHead: 'Subtitles Page',
    });
    console.log('Home Page!');
})

app.post('/subtitle/add', (req, res, next) => {
    let subtitles = [];
    sub_title: req.body.subtitleInput
    subtitles.push(sub_title)
    console.log(subtitles);
    res.render('index', {
        subtitles,
        topicHead: 'Subtitles Page'
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port 3000')
})
```

index.ejs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1><%= topicHead %></h1>
        <form name="form1" method="POST" action="/subtitle/add">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subtitle</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subtitleInput"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
            <% for (let sub of subtitles) { %>
                <h1><%= sub %></h1>
            <% } %>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

The error which I get;

```
ReferenceError: D:\code\getSub\views\index.ejs:25
    23|             </table>

    24|         </form>

 >> 25|             <% for (let sub of subtitles) { %>

    26|                 <h1><%= sub %></h1>

    27|             <% } %>

    28|     </main>


subtitles is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (D:\code\getSub\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:633:12), <anonymous>:14:24)
    at returnedFn (D:\code\getSub\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:668:17)
    at tryHandleCache (D:\code\getSub\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\code\getSub\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (D:\code\getSub\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\code\getSub\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (D:\code\getSub\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\code\getSub\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at D:\code\getSub\app.js:18:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\code\getSub\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem exists in this line `sub_title: req.body.subtitleInput`.
Perhaps you want something like this `let sub_title = req.body.subtitleInput;` in order to hold a value.
Anyway you don't need it, you could just push the input value directly like this.

```
let subtitles = [];
subtitles.push(req.body.subtitleInput)
console.log(subtitles);
res.render('index', {
    subtitles,
    topicHead: 'Subtitles Page'
});
```

In addition you have to check if `subtitles` is undefined because you use the same ejs file.

```
<% if (locals.subtitles){ %>
    <% subtitles.forEach(function (sub) { %>
        <h1><%= sub %></h1>
    <% }) %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But whenever I push a value to array it replaces the existing one, so it doesn't push. Why this happens?

Comment: that happens because with every new post, your code create a new array `let subtitles = [];`. If you want  to hold the previous posts you have to save input data in database.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. I moved array outside of app.post. With that it is ok now. Thanks for your help.